# How do I know which question increases the total questions count to #1,000,000?

Tags: discussion, statistics

I can see that every StackOverflow question has its own id, but how can I see which question is the question #1,000,000? In general: How can I find out the serial number of a question?

*Update*: As I get it now, is "serial number" the wrong expression. I'm asking for the first question which will let the total question count climb the million number range.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, I don't think it is that easy either.  There isn't any property of a question that would make it obvious.  The question number is approaching 4 million right now.  I assume that the question count is fairly heavily cached, far too expensive to calculate for every page refresh.  So the storm of page refreshes when it gets close isn't going to show the winner.  And it is very dynamic with questions getting deleted all the time, #1M can be (will be) #999,999 a second later.

Knowing the SO team, I bet they've programmed some kind of custom trigger that flashes a Unicorn page up for at least 5 minutes so the number is stable for at least that long.  Looking forward to it, hope it's a good question.  And have the honor to get the answer mark for it :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a [data explorer query](http://odata.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/577/) to find question number n. This doesn't include deleted questions.

Comment: Cool! Never know about this.

Comment: Note that if deleted question are not counted, the answer will change in time.

Answer (score 0):

Wel if you're talking 1,000,000 for the database Id then you can see the question here
 [Display Progress Bar at the Time of Processing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1000000)

Comment: This is just the 1 millionth post (could be answer or tag-wiki).

Comment: Well, it is the question number in this case, but it is an year old and counts other posts too.

Comment: The database ID counts questions and answers alike. It is already above 3 million

Answer (score 0):

You can probably see it in the blog.
I'm not how you can find it yourself. You can probably use the data dump to find the n<sup>th</sup> question, but it doesn't include deleted posts. Without deleted posts, you can't have a n<sup>th</sup> question.